# Identify duplicate entry for user, MySQL & PHP

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling, duplicates

I have a submission form that returns a MySQL error #1062 when a user tries to submit it with a duplicate entry. As an example, the error states:

```
Duplicate entry 'graphics' for key 'name'
```

I want to give the user a custom message that explains (in plain English) why they got an error, and what specific entry caused the error. For example:

```
"Graphics" is a duplicate entry and should not be used. Please remove it and resubmit the form."
```

The key will always be 'name,' but the duplicate entry itself will often be different. I need to be able to pull that specific value out of the MySQL error that's generated, and then wrap my custom message around it. How could this be done?

Comment: You could just pull all 'name' fields from the DB and then do a comparison check in PHP with the value specified by the user before you start inserting in your DB.

Comment: Don't you have the value inside a variable, when creating the query, and can't you use just that?

Comment: BTW. on a side note: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the deprecation process . Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either PDO or MySQLi.

Comment: @bono  i know only old mysql . is it difficult to learn  pdo and mysqli any good beginner tutorial on it apart from php.net . which teaches u from the bascis like update delte insert select functions from the basci sql

Comment: It's not difficult to learn at all, I got most of it down in 1 day. Here's a nice tutorial: http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: thank you very much i will try to learn from it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try to make a simple error check, displaying the user your error message if a mysql error occurs. You could try something like this:

```
$rows = mysql_query("SELECT `name` from `tbl` WHERE `name` = 'graphics';");

if(mysql_num_rows($rows) > 0){
    echo '"Graphics" is a duplicate entry and should not be used. Please remove it and resubmit the form.';
}else{
    insert...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check the table first before entering any data if the items you are inserting exist beforehand .

and second you can then print a custom message according to the error using if else loop
like

```
      $check_exists = // runs the code here to check if the entry graphics already exists for the existing name

     if ($post['name'] == ''){

     // error message for blank entry 

     }elseif($check_exists == true) {

   // custom error mesage for duplicate entry 

    }else {

  // submit the form here

    }
```

Comment: Though the idea is correct, the provided code isn't very useful

Comment: i code in this way  only . i am not too clear on the table structure i told him the logic to do so .

Comment: @bono if we write simle mysql queries then how will anyone learn . and he asked how to do it not to do for him :)

Comment: I was actually referring more to the $check_exists "code". Which really doesn't make any sense to me, since it's a variable how can it "run code to check".
Also though I agree that learning by yourself is the best way, this place is a place to learn :)

Comment: i know how to do it by comapring two values in basic sql but dint knew  in new sql that so recommends so dint write then .